# Include CSS file in typo3 login Page?

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I would like to load a CSS file in a TYPO3 login page.

Below is my code which I added in my ext_tables.php file.

```
if (TYPO3_MODE === 'BE') {
    $GLOBALS['TBE_STYLES']['inDocStyles_TBEstyle'] .= '@import "/typo3conf/ext/mytemplate/Resources/Public/Backend/css/login.css";';
}
```

But this is not working.

However, when I add inline style it's working fine.

```
$GLOBALS['TBE_STYLES']['inDocStyles_TBEstyle'] .= '
#t3-login-form:after {
  content: "\00a0";
  background-image: url("' . \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::extRelPath($_EXTKEY) . 'Resources/Public/Backend/Images/foo.png");
  width: 220px;
  height: 187px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  left: 201px;
  bottom: 533px;
}
';
```

But I want to import a CSS file.

I am using below extensions.

- typo3 6.2.14
- flux 7.2.1
- vhs 2.3.3
- fluidcontent 4.3.1
- fluidpages 3.3.1

Comment: thanks for the hint with the inline styles! works great under 7.6 :-)

Comment: Can you accept one of the answers if it worked for you?

Comment: inDocStyles_TBEstyle has been removed https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/8.0/Breaking-72392-RemovedDeprecatedCodeFromDocumentTemplate.html

Answer (score 1):

Since the other answers are outdated and not being updated:

For newer TYPO3 version >= v8, you should no longer use `inDocStyles_TBEstyle` (this was probably still possible when the question was posted).

Why importing the file (in the CSS snippet via [CSS @import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import)) did not work - that is not really TYPO3 specific but a CSS thing. You could check that in the browser with standards methods of troubleshooting, e.g. use the Developer Tools or look at the generated HTML source code and the generated snippet (e.g. CTRL+u in Chrome).

This might be an explanation:

> An @import rule must be defined at the top of stylesheet, before any other at-rule (except @charset and @layer) and style declaration, else it will be ignored.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import

---

**Alternative solution:**

For newer TYPO3 versions (such as v11), you can add CSS files as "skin" in your extension. This is not restricted to the login window.

1. Add something like this to your ext_tables.php (the directy is used, not the file!):

   ```
   $GLOBALS['TBE_STYLES']['skins']['mylogin'] = [
       'stylesheetDirectories' => [
           // the diretory, not the file !!! 
           'login' => 'EXT:mylogin/Resources/Public/Css/Backend/Skin',
       ]
   ];
   ```
2. Add the CSS file, to Resources/Public/Css/Backend/Skin/login.css

[Documentation for TBE_STYLES](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/Configuration/GlobalVariables.html#confval-TBE_STYLES) (this is a bit "thin" right now but might get updated at a later point).

**Notes**

Please also keep in mind the following changes for newer TYPO3 versions:

- the property `inDocStyles_TBEstyle` has been removed since TYPO3 v8, see changelog [Breaking: #72392 - Removed deprecated code from DocumentTemplate](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/8.0/Breaking-72392-RemovedDeprecatedCodeFromDocumentTemplate.html)
- do not use `$_EXTKEY` in ext_tables.php and ext_localconf.php (only in ext_emconf.php), just use the extension key as string, see (official documentation: TYPO3 Explained: [Rules and best practices for configuration files ext_tables.php and ext_localconf.php](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/BestPractises/ConfigurationFiles.html#rules-and-best-practices))
- use `$GLOBAlS['TBE_STYLES']`, not `$TBE_STYLES`

Answer (score 0):

In your `ext_tables.php` file, add something like this:

```
$GLOBALS['TBE_STYLES']['skins'][$_EXTKEY]['stylesheetDirectories'] = array();
$GLOBALS['TBE_STYLES']['skins'][$_EXTKEY]['stylesheetDirectories']['mystyles'] = 'EXT:' . $_EXTKEY . '/Resources/Public/Css/visual/';
```

Then put the stylesheet in the directory you defined. It will be loaded on all backend pages.

I'm not sure if there is a nicer solution to include the styles.

Comment: You should no longer use $_EXTKEY in newer TYPO3 versions in ext_localconf.php and ext_tables.php (only in ext_emconf.php). Just use the extension key. https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/BestPractises/ConfigurationFiles.html#rules-and-best-practices

Answer (score 0):

try something like this..

```
 $relativePath = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::extRelPath($_EXTKEY);
    $GLOBALS['TBE_STYLES']['logo_login'] = $relativePath . 'Resources/Public/Backend/Images/LogoLogin.png';
    $GLOBALS['TBE_STYLES']['logo'] = $relativePath . 'Resources/Public/Backend/Images/typo3-topbar@2x.png';
    $GLOBALS['TBE_STYLES']['inDocStyles_TBEstyle'] .= $relativePath . ' csspath ';
```

Comment: Can you add in which file this should go?

Comment: You should no longer use $_EXTKEY in newer TYPO3 versions in ext_localconf.php and ext_tables.php (only in ext_emconf.php). Just use the extension key. https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/BestPractises/ConfigurationFiles.html#rules-and-best-practices

Answer (score -1):

I use in one of my Extensions this one (in ext_tables.php) , but its for TYPO3 7.6. possibly it also fits with the version 6.2

```
$TBE_STYLES['skins'][$_EXTKEY]['name'] = $_EXTKEY;
$TBE_STYLES['skins'][$_EXTKEY]['stylesheetDirectories']['structure'] = 'EXT:' . ($_EXTKEY) . '/Resources/Public/Backend/Css/Skin/';
```

Greetings

Comment: Should be $GLOBALS['TBE_STYLES'] (not $TBE_STYLES) in newer TYPO3 versions. Is also $GLOBALS['TCA'] and not $TCA etc.